# Tricky regex parse on key value pairs

Tags: javascript, regex

I have spent over an hour messing with Regex patterns in order to get a `find-and-replace` on a complex string working right.

I need to convert a string like this:

```
foo a='b' c="d and e" wombat=true a fizz='buzz' "hello='goodbye'"
```

and normalize it into this:

```
foo "a='b'" "c='d and e'" "wombat='true'" a "fizz='buzz'" "hello='goodbye'"
```

In essence:

- Every `key/value` pair should be wrapped in double-quotes, with the value wrapped in single-quotes, regardless of how they were wrapped before.
- A multi-spaced value must be wrapped in single or double quotes before in order to be "included" as a value.

---

So far I'm playing with a Regex on the order of:

```
str = str.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)=("(.*?)"|'(.*?)')/g, '"$1=\'$2\'');
```

However, this has a ton of problems.

Is there any single-replace solution to this?

Comment: Why would `a` following `true` , before `fizz`  not be considered a value at `foo a='b' c="d and e" wombat=true a fizz='buzz' "hello='goodbye'"` ?

Comment: @guest271314 "A multi-spaced value must be wrapped in single or double quotes before in order to be "included" as a value."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Substituting

```
/(['"]?)(\w+)=(?:(['"])((?:(?!\3).)*)\3|(\S+))\1/g
```

with

```
"$2='$4$5'"
```

gives the wanted

```
foo "a='b'" "c='d and e'" "wombat='true'" a "fizz='buzz'" "hello='goodbye'"
```

---

The expression breaks down as follows:

```
(['"]?)            # group 1: either single or double quote, optional
(\w+)              # group 2: word characters (i.e. the "key")
=                  # a literal "="
(?:                # non-capturing group
  (['"])           #   group 3: either single or double quote
  (                #   group 4 (quoted value): 
    (?:(?!\3).)*   #     any character that's not the same as group 3
  )                #   end group 4
  \3               #   the quote from group 3  
  |                #   or...
  (\S+)            #   group 5 (non-quoted value, no spaces)
)                  # end non-capturing group
\1                 # whatever group 1 had, for good measure
```

Comment: Thank you. :) I've added a breakdown of the expression, too.

Comment: @dthree OBTW, note that you need to change `.` to `[\s\S]` if your values can contain newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

The below regex will fulfill your requirements:

```
"?(\w+)='?([\w]+)'?"?|"?(\w+)="([\w\s]+)""?
```

with substitution as:

```
"$1$3='$2$4'"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vX2nT1/2)

Comment: Also an idea but does not take spaced values in single quotes into account. [Another idea](https://regex101.com/r/xX0cO2/1).

Comment: Yeah that was not taken into consideration. But regex can be modified very easily for that.